# Apache Virtual Domains for staging

Tags: apache

We're trying to set up a staging service for domains configured on a server.

At present we have the following in our DNS and it is pointing to our server correctly.

```
*.server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au
```

This serves the default site located at:

```
/Server/http/_default
```

What I would like it to do is load a site based by the information in place of the wildcard.
Example;

```
test.com.server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au
```

would return the contents of:

```
/Server/http/test.com
```

Remembering that we might be using .com.au domain names too, so there'd be a requirement for anything before the "server001" part.

Answer (score 0):

You should define another `<VirtualHost>` block for `test.com.server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au` with its `DocumentRoot` pointing to `/Server/http/test.com`.

Something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
  DocumentRoot /Server/http/test.com
  ServerName test.com.server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au
  ErrorLog /var/logs/httpd/test.com/error_log
  CustomLog /var/logs/httpd/test.com/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au
  DocumentRoot /Server/http/_default
  ServerName *.server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au
  ErrorLog /var/logs/httpd/server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au/error_log
  CustomLog /var/logs/httpd/server001.stage.ourdomain.com.au/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The wildcard `VirtualHost` should be the last one since `apache` picks up the first `VirtualHost` that matches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we're looking to do this dynamically so there's no need to make changes to any of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) chapter in the manual. It basically explains how to use the [VirtualDocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) directive.